# jquery DatePicker gets clipped in Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, calendar

i have a horizontal iframe under the header image. Which has the reservation widget. all the fields are overflowing except for the date picker.

here is the test page  http://rosaliebay.com/dining-rh.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments yet, so here's what I'm thinking. The problem is that you are using an     iframe which makes it a window within a window. You need to include the booking section of your page in the same HTML page as the rest of the content. Is there a reason you chose to go with the     iframe?

Answer (score 0):

i Chose an iframe so its easy to paste in all the pages. otherwise I am dealing with 650 odd lines of code. and also if there's any future changes i can make them to just one file.